# Scrolling ends prematurely in ScrollViews combination - React native

Tags: react-native

I have a horizontal scrollView and a vertical scrollView after it. The vertical scrollview scrolls but ends prematurely. I think the height occupied by horizontal scrollview and navigation bar deducts the scroll portion at the bottom. How can I solve it? I've tested it in android devices.

Have a look at the video [here.](https://youtu.be/rwIe5Z64viE)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView }from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{marginBottom: 1}}>
          <View style={{width:100, height: 100, marginRight: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
          </View>
          <View style={{width:100, height: 100, marginRight: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
          </View>
          <View style={{width:100, height: 100, marginRight: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
          </View>
          <View style={{width:100, height: 100, marginRight: 1, backgroundColor: "red"}}>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>

        <ScrollView>
          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>1</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>2</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>3</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>4</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>5</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={{width:100, height: 200, marginBottom: 1, backgroundColor: "blue", justifyContent:"center"}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}>6</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

Have a look at it in expo:

https://snack.expo.io/BJ3zEZEgm

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have a proper explanation for why the scroll is short in some cases, but the simplest workaround I've found is to add `contentContainerStyle={{paddingBottom: insertValueHere}}` to the vertical ScrollView. Just adjust the height of the padding to fit your needs (for me it was the keyboard height where a KeyboardAvoidingView would not work). Hope that helps.